# Handling transient values with WPF converters

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a converter that I use to round numbers. It looks like this:

```
public class RoundNumberConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!value.IsNumber())
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        return Math.Round((float)value, 2).ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        float number;
        if (float.TryParse(value.ToString(), out number))
            return number;
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

This worked fine until I switched the UpdateTrigger to PropertyChanged. Now when I try to enter the value 1.23, the 1 character works as expected, but when I enter the period, 1. gets converted to 1.0, and because the value has not changed it doesn't get set in my viewmodel. In addition, 1. is converted to the string 1 when it is displayed in the textbox, so the user can not add a period. Does anyone have a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing this:

```
public class RoundNumberConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!value.IsNumber())
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        return Math.Round((float)value, 2).ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        var svalue = value.ToString();
        if (svalue.EndsWith(".")) // Prevents problems when using this with UpdateTrigger.PropertyChanged and user enters 1.
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        float number;
        if (!float.TryParse(svalue, out number))
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        return number;
    }
}
```